# Creating shortcuts for SAP GUI v7.2

Tags: sap-gui

How do you create shortcuts for the SAP GUI v7.2? I have read that it needs to have a shortcut file created that is a `*.ini` and that this needs to be formatted in a certain way. I can't find how to format it or where it needs to be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create shortcuts for the SAP GUI in version 7.2 you need to create a file titled "sapshortcut.ini" and place this file in the c:\WINDOWS directory. The SAP GUI will pull the information from this file and display the short cuts how you have written them. There is a certain format that needs to be followed in the file for everything to work correctly. You can use notepad++ to create this file.

```
[Label]
Key1="10) --- Production ---"
Key2="11) Your Environment Name"
Key3="12) PD1"

[Command]
Key1=-desc="---------------------" -type="-------------" -tit"10) --- Production ---"
Key2=-desc="Environment Description" -sid="Environment ID" -clt="Client Number" -gui="url to gui" -u="username" -l="language" -tit="11) Environment" -wd="Directory Path" -guisize="maximized"
Key3=-desc="Prod 1" -sid="PD1" -clt="100" -gui="Your GUI URL" -u="User123" -l="EN" -tit="12) PD1" -wd="C:\Documents and Settings\User123\SapWorkDir" -guisize="maximized"
```

Note: By default the GUI will organize based off of the "-tit" entry so I put numbers in the front of the entry to organize my shortcuts. Also note that Key1 is a fake shortcut, it is simply there for organization so all shortcuts underneath of it are part of the production landscape.